# I think rsync://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists does not match https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists, can you verify?

Tags: apt, rsync, https

I'm trying to maintain an rsync mirror of old-releases.ubuntu.com, and when I rsync the /ubuntu/dists directory, I get the same as what's found at https://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists. When I visit https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists, I get the versions I expect.

From the rsync path, I get bionic, devel, focal, groovy, etc., but in the https path, I see artful, breezy, cosmic, etc.

Could you confirm whether there's a protocol mismatch, or perhaps I've made a mistake in some way?

Here's what I see:

```
# rsync -av --delete rsync://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists . 
receiving incremental file list

sent 7,044 bytes  received 1,647,057 bytes  220,546.80 bytes/sec
total size is 66,910,170,553  speedup is 40,451.08
# ls dists
bionic            focal             hirsute            trusty
bionic-backports  focal-backports   hirsute-backports  trusty-backports
bionic-proposed   focal-proposed    hirsute-proposed   trusty-proposed
bionic-security   focal-security    hirsute-security   trusty-security
bionic-updates    focal-updates     hirsute-updates    trusty-updates
devel             groovy            precise            xenial
devel-backports   groovy-backports  precise-backports  xenial-backports
devel-proposed    groovy-proposed   precise-proposed   xenial-proposed
devel-security    groovy-security   precise-security   xenial-security
devel-updates     groovy-updates    precise-updates    xenial-updates
```

Thanks,
-rob

Comment: The same problem is happening here. Trying to rsync the old-releases mirror gives me something different to what's expected. Seems to be a problem with their web server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's based on rsync modules, not the domain itself only.

```
❯ rsync -avvv rsync://old-releases.ubuntu.com /tmp/ubuntu-cd
opening tcp connection to old-releases.ubuntu.com port 873
Connected to old-releases.ubuntu.com (91.189.91.123)
sending daemon args: --server --sender -vvvlogDtpre.iLsfxCIvu . /  (5 args)
This is an Ubuntu mirror - treat it kindly

releases        Ubuntu Releases CD Images
maas-images     MAAS images
simple-streams  Juju Simple Streams Mirror
lxc-images      Linux Containers (LXC/LXD) Images
cloud-images    Ubuntu Cloud Images
cdimage         Ubuntu CD Images
ubuntu          Ubuntu Archive
ubuntu-cloud-archive    Ubuntu Cloud Archive
old-releases    Ubuntu Old Releases
ubuntu-ports    Ubuntu Ports Archive
extras          Ubuntu Extras
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply on such an old thread. I'm sure I've worked around it by this point, but if I understand correctly, you're saying the rsync version won't necessarily match the https version, and that it's based on rsync modules. In your example, that suggests that it's sorted by server name, i.e. releases.ubuntu.com, maas-images.ubuntu.com, etc., including old-releases.ubuntu.com.

Comment: @RobSI I think that the HTTP(S) port would likely redirect you to the correct repository based on the server name. However, with the rsync protocol, Ubuntu might not route based on the domain/IP/hostname but rather on the module. I noticed this while working with specific repositories (such as port and old-releases).
i.e., `rsync rsync://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dst-dir/` are the same as `rsync rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu dst-dir/`

Comment: Thanks again, PSA. I've been using rsync to keep my repository updated from the rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu path. I understand that the rsync modules are the discrepancy between the rsync:// and https:// paths.

Comment: With help from user PSA, I've come to understand that the difference is caused by how rsync modules work. For the past couple of years, I've used rsync to keep a local repository from the path rsync://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu.